Problem with booting own operating system [32-bits]
Hey I have a problem when loading kernel, bootloader and protected mode works fine but when I try to call KERNEL_OFFSET there are glitches or loading problems and I can't figure it out.
Problem with Booting
source/boot.s
bits  16
org   0x7c00

KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000
VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000

boot:
    mov ah, 0x0
    mov al, 0x3
    int 0x10

    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl
    mov bp, 0x9000
    mov sp, bp

    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
    mov dh, 30
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 0x04
    mov cl, 0x02
    mov ch, 0x00

    int 0x13

    ;Enable A20
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 2
    jnz $
    mov al, 0xD1
    out 0x64, al
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 2
    jnz $
    mov al, 0xDF
    out 0x60, al

    lgdt [GDT_DESCRIPTOR]

    mov  eax, cr0
    or   eax, 0x1
    mov  cr0, eax

    jmp CODE_SEGMENT:protected_mode

GDT_START:
    dq 0x0

GDT_CODE:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

GDT_DATA:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
  
GDT_END:

GDT_DESCRIPTOR:
  dw GDT_END - GDT_START
  dd GDT_START

CODE_SEGMENT equ GDT_CODE - GDT_START
DATA_SEGMENT equ GDT_DATA - GDT_START

bits 32

protected_mode:
    cli
    cld

    mov ax, DATA_SEGMENT
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    mov ebp, 0x9FB00
    mov esp, ebp

    mov edx, VIDEO_MEMORY
    mov ebx, MESSAGE
    call print

    ; call KERNEL_OFFSET
    jmp $

print:
    mov al, [ebx]
    mov ah, 0x0F

    cmp al, 0
    jz .done

    mov word [edx], ax
    add edx, 2
    add ebx, 1

    jmp print
    
    .done:
        ret

halt:
    cli
    hlt

BOOT_DRIVE: db 0
MESSAGE: db "Hello, World!", 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

source/kernel.c
void kernel_main() {
    char* VGA_MEMORY = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *VGA_MEMORY = 'X';

    while (1);
}

source/linker.ld
ENTRY(kernel_main)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x1000;

    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        bss_end = .;
    }
}

makefile
all:
    mkdir -p build

    nasm -f bin source/boot.s -o build/boot.bin

    gcc -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -fno-pic -m32 -c source/kernel.c -o build/kernel.o

    ld -m elf_i386 -T source/linker.ld -o build/kernel.bin --oformat binary build/kernel.o

    dd if=/dev/zero of=image.bin bs=512 count=2880
    dd if=build/boot.bin of=build/os.bin conv=notrunc
    dd if=build/kernel.bin of=build/os.bin conv=notrunc bs=512 seek=1

    rm build/kernel.o build/kernel.bin build/boot.bin

run:
    qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=build/os.bin,format=raw,media=disk

I'm looking for a solve to begin loading the kernel. :>

os.bin or image.bin?

Also do a hex-dump of os.bin. Does it contain some recognizable data in known locations? Like 0xAA55 at byte-position 510? And the string Hello, World! a little bit before that?

For starters, you forgot to set up DS. You are also setting SP without setting SS.

Yes, it has.
https://pastebin.com/x83WTfad - hexdump of os.bin

@Jester In what sense is DS not set?

Not sure I understand your calculation of CODE_SEGMENT and DATA_SEGMENT.

That's fine. For ring 0 the byte offset in the GDT matches the selector value.

@stark I checked, but all calculations are done correctly CODE_SEGMENT and DATA_SEGMENT.

You don't set ES either, and mov dh, 30 makes no sense for a floppy. Also your makefile zeroes image.bin instead of os.bin so the latter will not be a full image and will even end in a partial sector. Fixing all of the above makes it work.

As pointed out by @Jester and shown in the comments, you have a number of problems:

mov dh, 30 is wrong - I would just mov dh, 0, but you'll want to see what it is specifically for your device
You should setup all the stack segment registers, you're missing ES. I would recommend setting up SS as 0x8000 and zeroing-out SP, that way you make a stack from 0x8000:0x0000, meaning you have around 64kb of stack.
You do dd if=/dev/zero to the wrong image file in your Makefile.

This should work. Hope this helps!
